# Shorthand animation working only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-animations

In Chrome, the following CSS3 animation works as I would expect, rendering an animation of the outline. However, in Internet Explorer and Firefox, this doesn't work.

```css
@keyframes outline-pulse {
  0% {
    outline: 10px solid green;
  }
  
  100% {
    outline: 0px solid green;
  }
}

.animate {
  animation: outline-pulse 1s linear 0; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="animate">
  <p>Content</p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be due to an oversight in the WD. In particular, it does not take into account shorthand declarations in keyframes, which almost always contain at least one non-animatable component property. In fact, the editors [confirmed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/0024.html) that this is a mistake:

> Yes, we absolutely intend that all values should be transitionable,
>   with the ones that don't have explicit rules just going by a
>   single-step transition.  It just hasn't been done yet.

And the text that is quoted from the 2013 WD has been updated in the [ED](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#keyframes):

> The keyframe declaration block for a keyframe rule consists of properties and values. **The properties defined by this specification are ignored in these rules**, with the exception of animation-timing-function,

Notice now that it only excludes the `animation-*` properties.

Whether IE and Firefox are in violation of the spec is debatable, since the spec hasn't reached maturity anyway. But unfortunately, unless Microsoft is willing to make an exception for this, it's very unlikely it will ever be fixed in IE. But there's a much better chance it'll be fixed in Microsoft Edge.

In the meantime, you'll need to take extra care to avoid specifying shorthands in keyframes; only change the properties that will actually be animated, and specify the rest in regular style rules.

Comment: Mind if I toss in a snippet in your answer following your advice?

Comment: @jdphenix: Go ahead!

Answer (score 2):

In order to have Internet Explorer and Firefox render this effect, you need to add an outline to the class definition. A 0 pixel outline will not change the appearance and make it work.

```css
@keyframes outline-pulse {
  0% {
    outline: 10px solid green;
  }
  
  100% {
    outline: 0px solid green;
  }
}

.animate {
  animation: outline-pulse 1s linear 0; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  outline: 0 solid green;  /* important bit */
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="animate">
  <p>Content<p>
</fieldset>
```

This is necessary because according to the [CSS Animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes) specification, regarding keyframe declaration blocks (emphasis mine):

> The keyframe declaration block for a keyframe rule consists of properties and values. **Properties that are unable to be animated are ignored in these rules**, with the exception of ‘animation-timing-function’,

As @Harry points out in comments, the `outline-style` property is not animatable, and it's presence in the keyframe declaration is ignored by Internet Explorer and Firefox as defined in the specification. Therefore, the `outline-style` must be declared in the class declaration to be shown.

Comment: This ate a few hours of my time today before I figured it out. I'd love to see a better explanation than "here's something that works!" because I really have no idea why the workaround works

Comment: It is the `outline-style` (which is not animatable) that seems to be causing the problem. If you just set `outline-style: solid` on the base class it works in FF for me. In Chrome v43 the snippet in question itself doesn't work. However, I think Chrome's current behavior is the correct one because the `0%` frame already specifies the style.

Comment: @Harry That's interesting. I'm not sure that Chrome's behavior is correct, since it seems reasonable to ignore non-animatable properties inside keyframes. The spec implies the non-animatable properties are simply ignored.

Comment: From https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes CSS Animations Spec, 4. keyframe declaration block "Properties that are unable to be animated are ignored in these rules..."

Comment: Fair point mate. I wonder why then Chrome moved from the correct behavior (in v43) to the current behavior. Maybe it is some behavior that Chrome/WebKit is trying to propose. (By the way, you can update my observation into your answer if you wish to. I don't have a problem :))