# Keyframes change content attribute not work on Firefox

Tags: css, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations

I want change content in class `.glyphicon-volume-down:before` (class icon in bootstrap) but only work on Google Chrome.

My keyframes don't change the `content` attribute but it is changing the color.

I don't know what I am missing? I don't want use JavaScript.

Here is my code :

```
.glyphicon-volume-down:before{
  /*name keyframes is w-spin*/
  animation-name:w-volume;

  /*time animation done is 2s*/
  animation-duration: 2s;

  /*delay time when start animation is 0s*/
  animation-delay: 0s;

  /*loop animation forever*/
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;

  /*effect animation run with the same speed from start to end*/
  animation-timing-function:linear;

  /*default pause animation*/
  /*animation-play-state:paused;*/

  /*repeat*/
  animation-direction: alternate;

  -webkit-animation-name: w-volume;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  /*-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;*/
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}


@-webkit-keyframes w-volume {
  0% {
    content:"text1";
    color:yellow;
  }
  100% {
    content:"text2";
    color: red;
  }
}

@keyframes w-volume {
  0% {
    content:"text1";
    color:yellow;
  }
  100% {
    content:"text2";
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation of `content` property does not work in Firefox because [it is not an animatable property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) and as per the working draft of the W3C specs any property that is not animatable will be ignored.

Quoting the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes): (emphasis is mine)

> The keyframe declaration block for a keyframe rule consists of properties and values. ***Properties that are unable to be animated are ignored in these rules***, with the exception of ‘animation-timing-function’

The above extract would imply that the behavior in Firefox is correct whereas the one in Chrome isn't but as BoltClock points out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734307/shorthand-animation-working-only-in-chrome), the spec's editor's draft has been updated and the updated text seems to imply that Chrome's behavior is the correct one. Maybe Firefox will change the behavior someday but since this spec has not reached maturity, it may take time.

> The keyframe declaration block for a keyframe rule consists of properties and values. ***The properties defined by this specification are ignored in these rules***, with the exception of animation-timing-function